# Reordering causing subview 's backround color to clear

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I m having issue of table cells reordering. I have some views with some background color in cell contenview.
When we drag cell for reorder its making all view's color to clear color.
its a standard behavior as much i understand.

Is there any way to not affect subview color while reordering?

Comment: can you put your code of cellForRowAtIndexPath: for more clarification .

Comment: Having the same problem.  Put a UIView inside a UITableViewCell and set the background color.  Make the table editable and drag to reorder the cell.  The background color of the UIView becomes clear while dragging the cell and returns when letting go.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior is to allow the user to see though the cell to best determine where to drop it, so strongly consider that use case before implementing something else.

You could try overriding `setHighlighted:` or `setSelected:` on the cell (or any applicable 
subviews like `UILabel`s) to ignore any changes when the controller is reordering.